# CSS or image for background and menu arrows?

Tags: html, css

Is is better to use CSS or image for these two cases:
1) Need a gradient like shading of purple on my homepage (color fades from dark purple to light purple)
2) All the menus on my site have an arrow "More " and when opened it changes to "Less "

Currently my design team has made the homepage as CSS and the arrows as images. But I cant see any advantage or disadvantage of one over the other or what is best practice to use?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what browsers you want to support.

1) If it needs to be cross-browser compatible across a wide range of browsers, go for an image.

2) I would stick with images for the arrows.  They *can* be made with CSS using border trickery, or canvas, but I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: Yes need cross browser as this is a social network but no IE 6 support so i don't have to support cave man age browsers. But can the CSS image look as good as a normal image or will it look stretched?

Comment: If CSS compatibility is not an issue, then CSS would have the benefit of having a faster download time for the user than the images.  Here is an example of how to generate css arrows:  http://www.dinnermint.org/blog/css/creating-triangles-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the use of images. They are supported over all browsers and old versions. You can further apply CSS styling to the images, if needed.

Using CSS to create icons and gradients is difficult and isn't supported across all browsers (especially IE).

Extra request for multiple images (that cache) > using CSS tricks that aren't cross browser